# Firebase Android - Write to Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a database like the one below for my Android app:

[image]

I want to create a new node with an unique ID each time a new user registers. The unique ID is from the email registration - not the Firebase generated ID. I know how to get that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Connection to `Firebase`

With your `Firebase` app set up, go to `Xcode` and open `GroceryListTableViewController.swift`. Where the properties are defined, add the following:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "grocery-items")
```

This establishes a connection to your `Firebase` database using the provided path. In the documentation, these `Firebase` properties are referred to as references because they refer to a location in your `Firebase` database.

In short, this property allows for saving and syncing of data to the given location.

You’ll notice that the base URL is not used. Instead, it uses a child path of grocery-items. The `Firebase` database is a `JSON` `NoSQL` database, so all data is stored as `JSON`.

`JSON` is a hierarchical key-value data structure—keys refer to objects that can contain values pointing to other objects. `JSON` data is simply a tree of key value pairs.

With `Firebase`, the key is a URL and the value is arbitrary data that could be a number, string, boolean or object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code in order to achieve your requirement:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
UserData userData = new UserData();
Map<String, Object> postValues = userData.toMap();
childUpdates.put("/Users/" + UniqueId, postValues);
mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Here, **userData** is a model class:

```
 public class UserData {

public String getLat() {
    return Lat;
}

public void setLat(String Lat) {
    this.Lat= Lat;
}


  public String getLng() {
    return Lng;
}

public void setLng(String Lng) {
    this.Lng= Lng;
}
public String Lat;
```

public String Lng;

```
public UserData (String Lat, String Lng) {
    this.Lng= Lng;
    this.Lat= Lat;
}

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("Lat", Lat);
    result.put("Lng", Lng);
    return result;
}
```

}

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Comment: Kindly, upvote the answer.

Comment: Done. Also, can you please explain what updateChildren does?

Comment: What it does is, updates the parent node (Users)  with a new child node.

Answer (score 0):

```
BHelper db =new DBHelper();// your dbHelper
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("firstName","Ahmad");
 values.put("lastName","Aghazadeh");
 long insertedId= db.getSQLiteDatabase().insert("user", "", values) ;


String sql = "INSERT INTO [user](firstName,lastName) VALUES (\"Ahmad\",\"Aghazadeh\"); select last_insert_rowid()";
 DBHelper itemType =new DBHelper();// your dbHelper`enter code here`
 c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
 if (c.moveToFirst())
    result = c.getLong(0);
```